# entity framework - navigation property does not load

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, foreign-keys, eager-loading

I have the following relation

[image]

```
public partial class SharedResource : DomainEntity
{
    public System.Guid Id { get; set; }
    public System.Guid VersionId { get; set; }

    public virtual PackageVersion PackageVersion { get; set; } // tried it noth with and without virtual
}
```

Now, I load SharedResource using

```
SharedResource sharedResource = Get(shareKey)
```

And

```
sharedResource.PackageVersion == null.
```

though VersionId is not null and

```
context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

What do I have to do in order to load it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`LazyLoadingEnabled` must be `true`, not `false`:

```
context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
```

`true` is the default if you don't set `LazyLoadingEnabled` at all.

And the `PackageVersion` property must be `virtual` to enable lazy loading for this property.

Or you can include the property directly in the query:

```
SharedResource sharedResource = context.SharedResource
    .Include("PackageVersion")
    .SingleOrDefault(s => s.Id == shareKey);
```